# Why is the filter function not working in R if a variable is used?

Tags: r

I want to create a subset of a dataframe by filtering. With my code, no rows are filtered (plotdata has 3 rows), unless I change the last "chip_id" variable to **434**.

What am I missing?

| name | value | chip_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 244 |
| b | 4 | 434 |
| c | 5 | 532 |

```
chip_id <- 434
analyzed_data <- read.csv("./test.csv",
                      #colClasses = c("chip_id"="factor", )
)
plotdata <- analyzed_data %>% filter(chip_id == chip_id)
```

Comment: I think you should name different objects differently in general. Did you try that? that might help.

Comment: If you need to distinguish between data and external variables, use pronouns like `filter(analyzed_data, .data$chip_id == .env$chip_id)`.

Comment: @memo Thanks! Naming them differently doesn't help in the end (at first it seemed to..).

Comment: @Axeman It solved my problem, thanks a lot! (Is it a different approach to the answer by @Dohamed?)

Comment: I think it is the same because it makes the evaluation of `chip_id` in the calling environment try `quo <- bquote(chip_id == .(chip_id))`then `analyzed_data %>% filter(eval(quo))`

Comment: I think the intent is much clearer with `.data` and `.env`, so I would use that.

Answer (score 1):

It is all about NSE (non-standard evaluation) it can work if you unquoting your global environment variable ,

```r
library(dplyr , warn.conflicts = FALSE)

analyzed_data <- data.frame(name = c("a" , "b" , "c") , 
                            value = c(3,4,5) , 
                            chip_id = c(244 , 434 , 532))
analyzed_data

#>   name value chip_id
#> 1    a     3     244
#> 2    b     4     434
#> 3    c     5     532

chip_id <- 434

plotdata <- analyzed_data %>% filter(chip_id == !!chip_id)

plotdata

#>   name value chip_id
#> 1    b     4     434
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>